# Can we have a dataset with slight difference in target values for same value of feature variable?

Tags: machine-learning, python, dataset, regression, data

I am trying to generate a dataset which involves 1 feature variable(`X`) and 1 target variable(`y`).

The feature variable represents values on the X-axis on the graph and target variable represents values on Y-axis.

Datatype of `X`: integer

Datatype of `y`: floating point

**I have `N` such graphs for same values of `X`, but a slight variation in `y` values.**

**One of the graph is as follows:**

[image]

I want to fit the data into a regression.

Now, my question is how to generate the dataset for this use case. Should I include values from all graphs into a single dataset? But, in this case, for every unique value of `X`, I will have `N` rows with same value of `X` and a different value of `y`?

I am doubtful about this approach.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's the context of your question but there's no problem with the approach you've outlined. Different values of `y` for the same unique value of `x` (over different rows, such that for example you have: `x = {1, 1}`, `y = {1, 2}`) are a natural result of the noise usually assumed in the model you fit (e.g. $y = x + \epsilon$).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Iyar, added the context. Can u judge it now. As, a slight variation in y values for same value of X cannot be considered noise in this case

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire why a slight variation in y values for same value of X cannot be considered noise in this case?

Comment: Hi Iyar Lin! It can't be considered as noise as the multiple entries got generated due to different genuine graphs as described in the use case