# Datasets with only single feature variable

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

**I mainly have 2 queries:**

1) I want to know if there are any standard datasets available who have single feature variable?

2) In these types of datasets, can there be some data points having same values for feature variable but a slight variation in target variable?

For exmaple, following table (X = feature variable and Y = target variable):

```
X | Y

1 | 2.345

1 | 2.3

2 | 3.76

2 | 3.7

3 | 4

4 | 5.56

4 | 5.57
```

Kindly let me know a few of them.

Comment: I am really trying to think of an answer to this, but meanwhile please answer my question, **why do you want a dataset like this?**

Comment: @BrunoGL, I have a use case: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/72131/can-we-have-a-dataset-with-slight-difference-in-target-values-for-same-value-of

Answer (score 1):

Finding a dataset with just two variables might be difficult because these would be a very naive dataset.

Therefore, what I would suggest, is for your to take a more complex dataset and pick two columns that you would like to analyse.

For example, you could look at this dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/sohier/calcofi#bottle.csv

Then, pick the column `Depthm` as your feature variable and the column `T_degC` are your target variable. These two columns seem to match the type of data that you expect.

Here is how these two variables look like (for `Depthm > 2000`)

[image]

or you could look at  another two variables instead, for example `Depthm` vs `Salnty`:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. Can you at least  tell If I should increase data from multiple graphs into single dataset for my use case

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire what I am suggesting is the opposite. Take a dataset with many (more than 2) variables but only work with the two variables that you want. In my answers I showed two examples of me doing that.